# node - what's wrong with my app?

Tags: linux, node.js

I've got httpd running on port 80 and I'm trying to bind a node app to port 8080.

Here it is:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, res){

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Obviously have run it from ssh command line via

```
node myApp.js
```

But whenever I type "http://*my-domain*:8080/" in the browser it just hangs and gives me nothing..

I've tried a range of different ports and listening on hostname 0.0.0.0, all giving the same result.

Have run netstat as comments suggested and results is :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3894/node
```

I'm using centOS on nan unmanaged VPS!

EDIT: Looks like its a firewall issue, could someone point me in the right direction as to how to configure the firewalls for a CentOS VPS.. ?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `netstat -ptan | grep 8080`?

Comment: Have edited question accordingly:)

Comment: Looks like it is running on port 22222 to me and not 8080. What made you grep for 22222?

Comment: Oh that was taken from trying to run it on 22222, ive tried it on 8080, 32, 8001 and a load of others all with the same result.

Comment: Is the machine running the server the same as your desktop? If so `http://localhost:8080` should work. If not what is the relationship between the client and the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be your firewall settings.  In the shell prompt on the server, try connecting with `curl`.

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/
```

If you can access it via the `localhost` but not via a browser then you most likely have a firewall issue.

If you can access the server via `localhost` then the next thing to do is to test the server from the outside via IP address.  If you can access it via IP address then you have a DNS issue.  If you cannot access it via IP address from the outside then you have firewall issue.

Firewall issues are platform specific.  We'd need to know the platform to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I can connect via curl and localhost!! Do you know how I can fix this firewall issue? Thank you so much man!!

Comment: I can access the httpd server via IP address but not the node one: ie, http://*my-server-ip*/ takes me to the php app but http://*my-server-ip*:8080/ doesn't. I recon that means I have a Firewall issue; I'm using CentOS on an unmanaged VPS

Answer (score 1):

try to write:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server running ');
```

the `.listen(8080);` is in the same line.

or to run it with `localhost:8080/` from the server may he block from outside