# Express Node.js not responding on live server

Tags: node.js

i have written a simple hello world program in express node.js and when i call it through Curl it's response is correct i.e it displays Hello world on the console but when i call the url from browser i get could not connect error.Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3039);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);
app.get('/partner', function(req, res){

    res.send('Hello World');
});
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: what page did you open in the browser?

Comment: test.com:3039/partner is the url and server file name is app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have either a DNS issue or a Firewall issue.

Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763215/node-whats-wrong-with-my-app/16763317#16763317) will help you.

Comment: The problem is that it works fine on localhost and also when i call the url through curl its response is fine but when i call in browser it shows cannot connect.I don't know what can be the possible reason.

Comment: @user2431743 is your browser configured to use a proxy server?

Comment: Check "netstat -na" and make sure that the listener is on 0.0.0.0 rather than 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Which cloud service you are using for node.js .share url of this page

Comment: The clould service is UKFast and operating system is centos.

Comment: did you check it on window azzure ? . share the url

Comment: I have this node.js app on window azzure cloud service http://blueapplesite.cloudapp.net